About Vaisvadeva ceremony
In this chapter of Markandeya Purana, it mentiones one offer bali to Duhsaha at the end of Vaisvadeva Ceremony:-

Men shall give thee a plenteous bali offering at the close of the Vaiśvadeva ceremony, first uttering thy name and then saying “this is for thee.

I wanted to know about this ceremony. So my question is:-

What is Vaisvadeva ceremony?
When does a man doing this ceremony and which deity decide to this ceremony?

